# No route matches [GET] "/no-sidebar.1.htm"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, coding-style

### I am currently developing my own website through ruby-on-rails. I am a beginner so I imported a "template" from "HTML5UP" into "PUBLIC" folder and working on it. I copied one of htmls, named "no-sidebar.html" from the template and created "no-sidebar.html.1.html" and when I run my project, I got an error messate like as below:

No route matches [GET] "/no-sidebar.1.htm"

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

You don't have any routes defined!
•Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.
• For more information about routes, please see the Rails guide Rails Routing from the Outside In.

---

I think I should add something to the routes but I do not know how I can make it. Please give me some advice..

By the way, I did not create any blog on my ruby-on-rails because I have been only using the template imported from HTML5UP site into the public folder. Should I still create a blog even if I use the template?

Thank you for reading my question and hope to find your advice soon.

All the best,
MJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct the name like: "no-sidebar.1.html.erb" then make sure you created the controller and defined the route correctly... or let me see your route.rb file

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice. The following is my route.rb file: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

...

Comment: Because I have imported a template from html5up and have never created even a blog yet. nothing is in my routes yet. http://html5up.net/landed

Comment: You did not create a controller?

Comment: Thats why you getting this error first create controler and add actions in it. Then define routes

Comment: Please check the documnetion of rails

Comment: If u need any help i will guude u